# Use Exiftools to add a tag with spaces and special characters to an image file

Tags: exiftool

When I compare a file that uploads correctly (into Mapillary) and a jpg file that fails in EXIFTOOLS I see that it doesn't have Create Date, Date/Time Original and Modify Date. There are lots of other fields as well but these are the only ones dealing with time.

[image]

When I try to use

```
'.\exiftool(-k).exe' -"Date/Time Original"="2019:10:27 18:14:10.5" Photo_2019_Jul_12_13_38_40_019.jpg
```

It doesn't let me add the tag (I assume) because it has a '/' in it. It also doesn't allow "Create Date" for example.
[image]

How can I create a tag with these?

Some sample files are in https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QCQdSvdk0RygfCqqRWaOj-IzBbj17gax?usp=sharing

Comment: did you get an error message of any kind?  On what do you base that assumption?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that - I get `.\exiftool.exe -"Date/Time Original"="2019:10:27 18:14:10.5" Photo_2019_Jul_12_13_38_40_019.jpg
Warning: Invalid tag name 'Date/Time'
Nothing to do.
PS Z:\My Drive\MGM_GC-Miscalaneous files\Misc_ToClean\MapillaryUpload_Test\files\issue>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [ExifTool FAQ #2](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q2)

"Date/Time Original" isn't the tag name, it's the tag description, which can change depending upon the set language (see the [`-lang` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#lang-LANG)). Tag names don't have spaces or special characters. The actual tag name to set a value is `DateTimeOriginal`.

So your command should be
`.\exiftool(-k).exe -DateTimeOriginal="2019:10:27 18:14:10.5" Photo_2019_Jul_12_13_38_40_019.jpg`

Though take note that `DateTimeOriginal` doesn't hold a subsecond value.  The location for that would be `SubSecTimeOriginal`.  But exiftool does have a shortcut.  If you set `SubSecDateTimeOriginal`, it will set the `DateTimeOriginal` and `SubSecTimeOriginal` tags.  Also, if you add a time zone to the end of that, it will set `OffsetTimeOriginal`, where the time zone value is held.

For example:
`.\exiftool(-k).exe -SubSecDateTimeOriginal="2019:10:27 18:14:10.5-04:00" Photo_2019_Jul_12_13_38_40_019.jpg`

Comment: Thanks.,.using SubSecTimeOriginal worked. Now I have to figure out how to run this as batch to read the `<DT_Value>=.\exiftool.exe -FileCreateDate Photo_*jpg` and use this to then run `.\exiftool.exe -SubSecDateTimeOriginal="<DT_Value>" Photo_*.jpg`

Comment: No need for scripting, use this command.  It will process all files in the directory.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.  You'll find it much faster than scripting a loop (see [ExifTool Common Mistake #3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3))

 
`exiftool "-SubSecDateTimeOriginal<FileCreateDate" -ext jpg C:\Path\to\Photos`